# IdentityServer4 - Google Chrome did not remove all cookies

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, idp

i have client application which tries to sign out and redirect user to authenticated page which should force user to login again.

But somehow after redirection to secured page. IDP responses that user is authenticated and there is a loop.
My logic detect incorrect user, force logout, user is logout, when he tries to open link ipd tell he is authenticated.

To logout I am using this:

```
 return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Request.GetDisplayUrl() }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to signout of both handlers (cookie + OpenID) using

```
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

Also, it is **important** to not return anything from your Logout, otherwise things will break.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```cs
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
```